# Android Firebase Notification Received as GCM

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am using android firebase notification in my android project and it is working perfect, except for some devices, firebase notification is not received, instead I get the following in Logcat :

> 05-17 17:38:22.292 27292-27292/com.example.myapp D/ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=com.example.myapp cmp=com.example.myapp/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver (has extras) }, ordered=true, receiver=com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver@422443a8
>
> 05-17 17:38:22.295 27292-27292/com.example.myapp E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error resolving target intent service, skipping classname enforcement. Resolved service was: tv.peel.app/com.peel.receiver.FCMService
>
> 05-17 17:38:22.411 27292-27292/com.example.myapp D/ActivityThread: BDC-RECEIVER handled : 0 / ReceiverData{intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=com.example.myapp (has extras) } packageName=com.example.myapp resultCode=-1 resultData=null resultExtras=null}

where com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE is for GCM which I've never used in my app before!!!
P.S : I use php curl to send data payload via firebase notification and it is working except for the above.

```
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $data
);
$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

and the $result is :

> {
>     "multicast_id": 5419052642417855073,
>     "success": 1,
>     "failure": 0,
>     "canonical_ids": 0,
>     "results": [
>       {
>         "message_id": "0:1526567349119146%bc732c83f9fd7ecd"
>       }
>     ]
>   }

Edit : 
Services in Manifest :

```
<service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: The `c2dm` intent is not a problem.  It is used by Firebase.  See the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver

Comment: what about the second line in logcat : Error resolving target intent service ?

Comment: Do you have the [Peel app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tv.peel.app&hl=en_US) installed on the device?  There may be some conflict with it.  `FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver` attempts to deliver received events to an instance of `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and it seems to be finding multiple targets.  It's choosing `tv.peel.app/com.peel.receiver.FCMService`

Comment: [The docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService) indicate you should declare your Instance ID service in the your manifest with `exported=true`.  See if that fix helps. (Same is true for

Comment: Peel app is installed, and after uninstalling it is conflicting with another app.

Comment: Instance Id service is declared in manifest with exported = true, and so for FirebaseMessagingService and FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver. still the same problem

Comment: I tried using android:priority="1000" for FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver and that worked, but that affected my other apps, i.e when a notification is sent for another app it is now redirected to this app